# Fipy Change CellValue between solving timesteps

Tags: fipy

I want to connect a mesh (partial differential equations) with a complex mixture reactor (ordinary differential equations). I want to take the values in one point, solve the ODEs, and reinput the values in the mesh (in which PDEs will be solved).

```
 # Geometry
Lx = 2   # meters
Ly = 2    # meters
nx = 101 #int((Lx / 0.05) + 1) # nodes
ny = 101 #int((Ly / 0.05) + 1)

# Build the mesh:
mesh = Grid2D(Lx = Lx, Ly = Ly, nx = nx, ny = ny)
X, Y = mesh.cellCenters
xx, yy = mesh.faceCenters

C0_DO = 10. #mg/L # Dissolved Oxygen initial concentration
C0_OM = 5.
T0 = 28. #mg/L # # Temperature
print(f'DO saturation concentration: {calc_DOsat(T0)} mg/L')

# Dissolved oxygen:
C_DO = CellVariable(name="concentration_DO", 
                 mesh=mesh, 
                 value=C0_DO,
                 #hasOld=True
                 )

# Temperature
T = CellVariable(name="temperature", 
                 mesh=mesh,
                 value=T0,
                 #hasOld=True
                 )

C_OM = CellVariable(name="concentration_OM", 
                 mesh=mesh, 
                 value=C0_OM,
                 #hasOld=True
                 )

# Transport parameters (diffusion constants)

# Dissolved oxygen diffusion constant
D_DO = 2. #m2/s
D_DO = FaceVariable(name='DO_diff', mesh=mesh, value=D_DO) # This is necessary to set a fixed-flux boundary condition
D_DO.constrain(0., mesh.exteriorFaces) # This is necessary to set a fixed-flux boundary condition


D_OM = 2.

# Reaction and source terms

O_R = 1. # Re-aeration temperature correction factor (-)
Y_R = 1. #reaeration_rate() # Re-aeration rate (1/day)
DOsat = (14.652 - 0.41022 * T + 0.007991 * T ** 2 - 0.000077774 * T ** 3) # Oxygen saturation concentration (mg/L)
xi_SOD = 0.1 # Sediment Oxygen Demand (BC) (1/day)

# Oxygen transport-reaction
eqDO = (TransientTerm(var = C_DO) == # Transient term
        DiffusionTerm(coeff = D_DO, var = C_DO) # Diffusion term
        + (mesh.facesTop * (Y_R * (O_R ** (T.faceValue - 20)) * ((14.652 - 0.41022 * T.faceValue + 0.007991 * T.faceValue ** 2 - 0.000077774 * T.faceValue ** 3) - C_DO.faceValue))).divergence #Top Boundary Condition (fixed-flux)
        + (mesh.facesBottom * (xi_SOD * C_DO.faceValue)).divergence # Bottom Boundary Condition (fixed-flux)
        )

eqOM = (TransientTerm(var = C_OM) == # Transient term
        DiffusionTerm(coeff = D_OM, var = C_OM) # Diffusion term
        )

eqTOT = eqDO & eqOM


    def reactor_model(C, t):
      k1 = 0.5
      k2 = 0.1
    
      C1 = C[0]
      C2 = C[1]
    
      dC1dt = -k1 * C1
      dC2dt = -k1 * C1
    
      dCdt = [dC1dt, dC2dt]
      
      return dCdt



  # PDESolver hyperparameters
steps = 10
sweeps = 2
dt = 1e-1
reactor_act = True

t = time.time()
for step in range(steps):
  C_DO.updateOld()
  C_OM.updateOld()
  
  for sweep in range(sweeps):
    eqTOT.sweep(dt=dt)

  if reactor_act:
    # Reactor
    r_in = [C_DO([(Lx/2), (0)]).mean(), # Dissolved Oxygen reactor input
            C_OM([(Lx/2), (0)]).mean()  # Organic Matter reactor input
            ]

    print('Reactor input:', r_in)

    # solve ODE
    C = odeint(reactor_model, r_in, np.linspace(0, dt, 10))
    r_out = C[-1]

    print('Reactor output:', r_out)

    # Reinput ODE
    C_DO.setValue(r_out[0], where=(Y >= Ly - mesh.dy / 2 ) & (X <= (Lx/2 + mesh.dx / 2)) & (X > (Lx/2 - mesh.dx / 2)))
    C_OM.setValue(r_out[1], where=(Y >= Ly - mesh.dy / 2 ) & (X <= (Lx/2 + mesh.dx / 2)) & (X > (Lx/2 - mesh.dx / 2)))
  
    C_DO.setValue(r_out[0], where=(Y <= mesh.dy / 2 ) & (X <= (Lx/2 + mesh.dx / 2)) & (X > (Lx/2 - mesh.dx / 2)))
    C_OM.setValue(r_out[1], where=(Y <= mesh.dy / 2 ) & (X <= (Lx/2 + mesh.dx / 2)) & (X > (Lx/2 - mesh.dx / 2)))

elapsed = time.time() - t
print('Calculation completed')
print(f'Runtime: {elapsed/60} minutes')
```

However, I see that the variables after .setValue are not used for the new iterations. I understand that there is some variation due to the diffusion, but I think this much is not correct:

```
Reactor input: [9.63329852994412, 4.999999999999067]
Reactor output: [9.1634771  4.53017857]
Reactor input: [9.387521550064774, 4.999830239918787]
Reactor output: [8.9296868  4.54199549]
Reactor input: [9.151030178165843, 4.999737004369599]
Reactor output: [8.70472925 4.55343608]
Reactor input: [8.92773098935664, 4.999650988910076]
Reactor output: [8.49232049 4.56424049]
Reactor input: [8.72052727373096, 4.999567509355334]
Reactor output: [8.29522222 4.57426245]
Reactor input: [8.529743672332394, 4.999485929361331]
Reactor output: [8.11374324 4.5834855 ]
Reactor input: [8.354632596585608, 4.9994060376006795]
Reactor output: [7.94717243 4.59194587]
Reactor input: [8.194109569439474, 4.999327684297063]
Reactor output: [7.79447821 4.59969632]
Reactor input: [8.04703351109057, 4.99925073845838]
Reactor output: [7.65457513 4.60679236]
Reactor input: [7.912305097814226, 4.999175081285443]
Reactor output: [7.5264175  4.61328748]
Calculation completed
Runtime: 0.09242624044418335 minutes
```

[image]

Is there any way to change the CellValues between iterations?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us your equations? Either as math or as code (preferably both)? If you're equations are *fully* implicit, then no, your changes won't be "seen" on the next solve.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you're actually setting any values? The mask `(X <= (Lx/2 + mesh.dx / 2)) & (X > (Lx/2 - mesh.dx / 2))` looks like it has the potential to exclude all cells.

Comment: @jeguyer I added the full code.

Comment: Ok, I think that the problem is not in the computation of the solution, but the diffusion of the closer cells, which return the "reactor" to the original value (which is correct physically and mathematically).

Comment: I haven't had a chance to do any tests, yet, but I agree with your assessment. My suggestion would be to try to move these reactor assignments inside the sweep loop. I wouldn't recalculate them each sweep, at least not to start, just keep reassigning.